# Clinical records dataset and drawing some useful and interesting conclusions out of it

Tags: self-study, statistical-significance, data-visualization

I am trying to draw some conclusions from a dataset like the one below. My real dataset is longer and different, but this one represents decently some clinical tests under study. These data are still far from being input for a model, but any answer will give me a direction what to look for. For a start, **I am looking into producing some useful visualisations and tables and I would gratefully accept some hints.**

To describe what you read below, the tests concern some hormones (A, B, C, ...). Column "add" hosts the units that should be added and column "added" hosts the units that were actually added. The "diff" expresses the difference between the two previous columns and "action" is a column where a comment has been added (such as if the action taken was non-recommended or the units added were more/less than recommended, etc.). Column "initial" and "final" show respectively the initial and the final levels of sufficiency of the hormone in the body before and after action was taken.

```
  hormone  add  added       diff           action      initial   final
0       A    2    2.0          0   as recommended       Insuff  Insuff
1       A  NaN    NaN        NaN   as recommended         Over    Suff
2       A   10    9.0          1             less  Partly suff    Suff
3       B  add    NaN  unapplied        unapplied  Partly suff  Insuff
4       B  NaN    1.0         -1  non-recommended       Insuff    Suff
5       B   30    3.0         27             less  Partly suff    Suff
6       B   30   32.0         -2             more  Partly suff    Over
7       C    5    5.0          0             less       Insuff  Insuff
```

To elaborate a bit further, I had the following thoughts, but they are so messy in my head.

1) A histogram with hormones on x axis which will show how many actions per hormone were 'as recommended', 'non-recommended' etc.

2) Prioritise the levels of sufficiency using numbers (e.g. Insuff --> 0, Partly Suff --> 1, etc.). Then, count the cases where the sufficiency dropped and create a histogram for these cases only and hue the bars depending on the actions "as recommended", "non-recommended" etc.

3) Count the cases where the levels of sufficiency exceeded ("Over") and create a histogram for these cases only and again hue the bars depending on the actions "as recommended", "non-recommended" etc.

*I am totally new here, so if my question should be out of this website, please direct me through your comments where I should post it.*

Many thanks in advance ^_^

Answer (score 0):

If this shows eight lines of real data, then I’d address some fishy things before much visualization.

- It’s awkward to show *add* minus *added* in the column *diff*; it’d be more intuitive to display *added* minus *add*, i.e. how much the treatment exceeded the recommendation.
- Why are there NaN’s but no zeroes in the *add* column? I’d expect to see some NaN’s, where no recommendation was made, and also some 0’s, with a recommendation for no supplementation.
- Why did the hormone level in row 1 go from too high to sufficient? Does hormone A self-regulate? And how did a patient with a hormonal excess get into a study on hormone supplementation?
- Why did the partially sufficient cases in rows 5-6 get higher recommended and added amounts than the insufficient case in row 4? This suggests that some important factor is missing from the dataset.

Meanwhile, if this is fake data, then there probably isn’t enough good information here for us to answer the question at all.

Comment: Oops — I just saw that the question was edited two hours ago but asked three years ago. I wouldn’t have answered if I had realized the question was so old.